# TensorFlow Docker Images on CentOS

Tags: docker, tensorflow, centos

TensorFlow Official Supports a limited set of Operating System. If I use the tensorflow docker image on CentOS would that be a supported configuration?

I understand that I can get TensorFlow to work, I am cwondering about being an approved configuration

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you use Docker, you can install Ubuntu as base image. You should definitely try Nvidia Cloud GPU. It is a free docker from Nvidia to use tensorflow or any other framework from a container.